# add and increase number for text field input

Tags: swift, macos

I'm working on a software which has a batch processing component. You can insert a name for each object you want to create and you can choose how much objects you want to create based on the informations given.

If you name the object *test* and **create it 50 times**, you'll have 50 or more objects named test. What I want to achieve is to get *test*, *test-**1***, *test-**2***, *test-**3***, etc. You know what I mean ^^

Title / name comes from an UITextField as a string, quantity comes from there too as an Integer.

My class:

```
class Device: NSObject {

var name: String = ""
var uuid: String = ""
var online: Bool = false
var autoStart: Bool = false
```

}

My method:

```
// create new devices based on data from modal
    var devices = [Device]()
    let quantityDevices = quantityData.intValue

    for _ in 0...quantityDevices-1 {

        let newDevice = Device()
        print("created new device")

        newDevice.name = titleData.stringValue
        devices.append(newDevice)
    }
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the variable in the `for` and append it as a string to the name.

```
for i in 0...quantityDevices-1 {

  let newDevice = Device()
  print("created new device")

  newDevice.name = titleData.stringValue + "-\(i)"
  devices.append(newDevice)
}
```

Comment: @Jakob No problem, don't forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: on the way, I've got a lock down on this ("you can accept as answer in 31 seconds") ^^

Comment: thank you <3 - glad to have people with more knowledge to ask for help if needed. Maybe I can give something back later my life :D